# UPN - User Principal Name

Tags: active-directory, upn

How I get my UPN from Active Directory? I need to test an app which uses Upn Claim type...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This command should work.

```
C:> whoami /upn
```

The whoami.exe command comes with Windows Vista and later, but for those on XP you can download it as part of the XP Support Tools [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=49AE8576-9BB9-4126-9761-BA8011FABF38&displaylang=en).

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?  I believe whoami.exe comes with Vista and later, but if you are on Windows XP, you can download the Windows XP Support Tools (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=49AE8576-9BB9-4126-9761-BA8011FABF38&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 0):

If you have administrative rights in Active Directory, you can run Active Directory Users and Computers and look at the Account tab of the User Properties window and see it with it being a combination of the User logon name and the domain suffix (first one listed).